# Closer in the sense of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a statement 'Suppose there are vectors $U_1, U_2,...,U_n$, which are successively closer to another vector $V$, in the sense of inner product'.
What does this actually mean? Can we specify distance with the help of inner product?
I tried with an example which is valid in my case, i.e. let $U_1=[2 \  1]$, $U_2=[0 \ 1]$ and $V=[1 \ 1]$.  Both the vectors $U_1$ and $U_2$ are at same distance from $V$, and $<U_1,V>=3$ and $<U_2, V>=1$.
I am not able to draw any conclusion from this.
Any insight into this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are infinitely many $U_i$, is that right? Because you seem to have stopped at $U_n$.

Comment: No, in my case $V$ is the mean vector and $U_i$, the column vectors of square root of covariance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In an inner product space $(V,<>)$, the distance between vectors $u,v\in V$ is defined as $||u-v||=\sqrt {<u-v,u-v>}$. So you simply use this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please give me a proper reference where I can go through it in detail?

Comment: @Rahul, Elementary Linear Algebra by Anton Rorres, or almost any book on Linear Algebra